# Loading and Caching Time-based Data

Tags: objective-c, database, caching

I'm looking for a good way of caching event entries from a big database so that it's not necessary to load the whole database but only timeframes which contain entries which are currently displayed, selected or otherwise needed. Are there classes in Cocoa or Objective-C programming pattern which provide support to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a property database which pulls down list of available properties for sale.  The easiest way I found to do this, was to have a date attribute which gets set when the data is first populated.  From then on, only the objects which have a time that's expired are updated when someone attempts to view a property.  This was the easiest way I found to control the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you go a bit more into technical details? For example: of which classes and patterns did you make use of to implement your solution.

Comment: Well, the way I did it was to use Core Data as a local data store. I'd populate core data with an initial download of data and date each entry added.  Then any time the entry was viewed (if the date passed the expiry date), it would pull down the data only for that item instead of a complete set.  There weren't really any classes specifically, just Core Data with a date attribute.  Any type of data store would do the job, as long as you store a date somewhere - you could create a custom class and use NSKeyedArchiver to write content to disk.